# On click returns null instead of an object

Tags: reactjs, callback, storybook

It's really basic I guess. I'm trying to add onClick callback to my script & I believe I'm missing a value that would be responsible for finding the actual item.

Main script

```
import React from 'react';
import { CSVLink } from 'react-csv';
import { data } from 'constants/data';
import GetAppIcon from '@material-ui/icons/GetApp';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const handleClick = (callback) => {
    callback(callback);
};

const DownloadData = (props) => {
    const { callback } = props;
    return (
        <>
            <CSVLink
                data={data}
                onClick={() => handleClick(callback)}
            >
                <GetAppIcon />
            </CSVLink>
        </>
    );
};

DownloadData.propTypes = {
    callback: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default DownloadData;
```

Storybook code

```
import React from 'react';
import DownloadData from 'common/components/DownloadData';
import { data } from 'constants/data';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

export default {
    title: 'DownloadData',
    component: DownloadData,
};

export const download = () => (
    <DownloadData
        data={data}
        callback={action('icon-clicked')}
    />
);
```

So right now with this code on click in the storybook I'd get null and I'm looking for an object.

Comment: `callback(callback)` what do you expect to happen here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the potential issues I can see is that your `handleClick` function is stored as it is in-memory, when you import the component. That means you're keeping reference of something that doesn't exists and expects to use it when rendering the component with the callback prop.

**Each instance of a component should have its own function.** To fix it, move the function declaration inside the component. Like this:

```js
const Foo = ({ callback }) => {
  // handleClick needs to be inside here
  const handleClick = callback => {
    console.log("clicked");
    callback(callback);
  };

  return <div onClick={() => handleClick(callback)}>Click me!</div>;
};
```

[Check this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cloud-7y4wl).

If this doesn't fix your problem, then there is something wrong with how you're implementing Storybook. Like a missing context.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! Unfortunately, the handleClick then is getting the undefined ref error on click.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Because my example works. Logging the action callback returns the correct function from Storybook: `function actionHandler()`